# How to connect MySQL in Linux Server?

Tags: linux, mysql

I've been trying so hard just to connect with MySQL in my Linux server account. However when I run `mysqladmin -u root -p`, it generates this prompt:

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' (2)'
Check that mysqld is running and that the socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock' exists!
```

Then when I tried this:

```
mkdir /var/run/mysqld
touch /var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock
```

it will prompt

```
touch: cannot touch `/var/run/mysqld/mysql.sock': Permission denied
```

Can anyone help me if there is any workaround or a solution for this?

Comment: Have you ensured MySQL server is running? Have you tried editing the file as root?

Answer (score 0):

Don't try to `touch` the file. It's not up to you to do that.

Your MySQL server doesn't appear to be running. How to start it depends on your Linux distribution (Debian? Gentoo? Red Hat?), but it's probably something like

`sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

or

`sudo service mysql start`

Then try again.

It may also be the case that MySQL isn't listening on a UNIX socket. Try to run

`mysql -h localhost -u root -p`

(I am assuming `myadmin` is a typo in your message; you probably meant `mysqladmin` or similar)

Comment: :it seems like I cannot use the sudo command since I don't have sudo password.

Comment: The `sudo` password is your user's password. I assumed you had root rights on that server - don't try to `sudo` if we're talking about shared hosting! Is this the case? Or is this a Linux machine under your control?